# Flask URL Route Registrations

Tags: python, flask, routes

In Flask's Route Registration functionality, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#url-route-registrations, can you do the following:

```
@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>/line/<int:line>/word/<string:word>')
```

So, in the above example, we want to go to a specific word, on a specific line, on a specific page.

Essentially my question is, does the variable part need to be the last part of the URL, or can you append more bits to it?

**EDIT**:
What I'm saying is, all the examples I've seen so far look like so:

```
@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>')
```

but can you do this:

```
@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>/sentence/<int:sentence>')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add query string parameters to the url, such as `?search=blue` for example, but you couldn't add another "folder" such as `.../<string:word>/character`, as then the route would not match the entry in the route map.

But if you simply want to define the route and not have the last part be a variable, that is fine - for example

`@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>/line/<int:line>/word/<string:word>/test')`

Edit:

```
@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>/sentence/<int:sentence>')
```

would also be fine - it is no different to the first example you gave in your question.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Before I delve deeper into this, I'm still trying to determine if Flask is built for what I want to do. If you don't mind, could you confirm? One example is, a user accesses a URL, such as http://localhost:8080/test/sensor/sensor1                                             Flask must then query the database for 'sensor1', and return the data as a CSV file for the user to download. Is Flask the way to go for this?       The request can also be http://localhost:8080/test/sensor/sensor1/date/2001-01-01, hence my previous question. Thanks!

Comment: Flask can definitely do this. You would just register two routes, one with the date and one without. And the output of a CSV file is no problem either, you just generate a response with `send_file` or similar.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Thanks Matt, you have been very helpful. Are you a full-time Flask developer?

Comment: At the moment I mix my time between perl legacy code and flask for new stuff ☺

Answer (score 2):

What you've done is perfectly acceptable. Here's a minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>/line/<int:line>/word/<string:word>')
def user_page(page, line, word):
    return '{} {} {}'.format(page, line, word)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Open your browser and navigate to `http://localhost:5000/users/page/5/line/47/word/something`.

And Flask will happily return:

`5 47 something`